# I am developing a website in which i want to read some json file locally in my js file

Tags: javascript, html

```
data = {"items": [
                   {
                        "title": "sample 1",
                        "author": "author 1"
                   },
                   {
                        "title": "sdample 2",
                        "author": "author 2"
                   }
]};
```

This is my json file.

Now I want to read this local json file in my js to print the values of json in HTML page
I dont want to use any httpsRequest.

NOTE: I am not using any web server

Below is my JS file

```js
function data(languageClass){
  var news = document.getElementsByClassName(languageClass)[0];
     var item = json.items;// where json is local json copy which i want
 console.log( "hiiii" + item);
  for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      var h5 = document.createElement("h5");
      
      h5.innerHTML = item[i].title;
   
      news.appendChild(h5);
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.innerHTML = item[i].author;
      news.appendChild(p);
 }
  
  
}
```

below is my HTML file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="D:/Shubhankar/web/quess.json"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../web/Question.js"></script>

<title>Java Interview Question</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/icon.png">
</head>
<body onload='data("interviewQuestions")'>

    <div class="interviewQuestions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't load JSON through a script tag (and that's not valid JSON anyway - you can't define variables). Just use a JavaScript file that defines an object instead.

Comment: Your `function data()` will overwrite `var data = "{}";`! Also I don't think you can load `D:/...` because of cross-origin (check console). Also `json.items` should be `data.json`

Comment: Could you then help me in getting/putting my json file using web server.

Comment: Too broad for SO to help you with setting up server. Try installing XAMPP or other tools

Comment: `var data = require('/path/to/json_file.js')` on top of your Question.js file

Comment: require() is a nodejs function.... can you help me how to use node JS in my code

Comment: You can't use nodejs on a web page. It's server side. also require is not (just) a node function. You can use the [requirejs library](http://requirejs.org/) to enable this. Basically, this is obvious to me to complex for your knowledge level. Don't use require.

Comment: @DanWhite I think your trying to make the OP run before he can walk with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {"items": [
                         {
                           "title": "sample 1",
                           "author": "author 1"
                         },
                         {
                          "title": "sdample 2",
                          "author": "author 2"
                         }
]};
```

This is not a valid JSON.

Without web server or XHR request, you cannot load your data. One way to get this data in your app is to have a JS file with JSON content in it.
Sample:

```
var data={"items": [
    {
      "title": "sample 1",
      "author": "author 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "sdample 2",
      "author": "author 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now call this JS file using `script` tag.

`<script src="path/to/jsonfile.js"></script>`